# Analytics Measurement Protocol - how do I use the Client ID?

Tags: javascript, php, google-analytics

**TL;DR:** Can't find clear information on how to set/get the **Client ID** to make any server-side tracking request. Need to understand how to work with the Client ID.

---

I'm planning to use [Analytics Measurement Protocol](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/devguide) to send a custom pageview from the server (I'm using PHP).

Standard page-track request looks like this:

```
v=1              // Version.
&tid=UA-XXXXX-Y  // Tracking ID / Property ID.
&cid=555         // Anonymous Client ID.

&t=pageview      // Pageview hit type.
&dh=mydemo.com   // Document hostname.
&dp=/home        // Page.
&dt=homepage     // Title.
```

In order to make the request, I need to set `cid` (Client ID). This is what the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/parameters#cid) tells about it:

> Required for all hit types.
>
> This anonymously identifies a particular user, device, or browser
>   instance. For the web, this is generally stored as a first-party
>   cookie with a two-year expiration. For mobile apps, this is randomly
>   generated for each particular instance of an application install. The
>   value of this field should be a random UUID (version 4) as described
>   in http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4122.txt

For me, the whole point of using the Analytics Measurement Protocol is **not to use JS** to track specific hits. JS can throw errors, older browsers might not be so developer-friendly, users tend to use browser extensions to block not only ads, but trackers as well. Having said that:

1. Is there any way to get the Client ID in PHP, and do I even need to
   do that?
2. Can I just generate a random UUID (v.4) every time I need to send a
   pageview or an event?
3. I understand the Client ID should be unique per client. How do I make sure it really is?

Let me add, I'm using a legacy code with the old **ga.js** library fueling Google Analytics.

**UPDATE:**

I found a [post](http://mudd.com/blog/google-analytics-measurement-protocol-for-php-campaign-tracking/) by Dave Meindl from 2013, showing an example implementation. Seems like he basically creates the an UUID every time and uses it as the Client ID. If someone could confirm that that's the way to go, I would be so happy.

Comment: You create it every time when you want a series of individual, disconnected hits. If you want the data to be aggregated into sessions and users you need a way to maintain a unique client id per user (actually in web tracking the client id is set per browser or device). You can store the client id in a PHP session (and/or cookie) and pass it in to your tracking function.

Comment: @EikePierstorff As you know from my previous post, I need to track registrations. This means the custom pageview I'm triggering will be sent just once per user. In this case I could simply generate the Client ID right when I need it, making sure it's unique. So no need to store it in the session or in a cookie. Does this make sense? The server-side tracking will be working only for this specific case - registration. The rest remains good old JS.

Comment: As long as you do not need the data aggregated into sessions you can put there whatever you want and do not need to store it anywhere (this is not a usual use case and thus not covered by documentation). The uuid format is simply to avoid naming collisions so two unrelated pageviews will not be merged into a unique user. But you can just as well count from zero to infinity for all that GA cares.However if you want to connect your registration goal to pageviews that happened before - then you need to read the client id from the _ga cookie and reuse it, or maintain your own session.

Comment: @EikePierstorff In other words, if I want the aggregation, I need to read the `clientId` with JS, and then pass it with Ajax to the server to make the hit call? Assuming a user blocks Analytics tracking, would I be able to even do that? Also, no idea how to get the `clientId` via `_gaq` object. Examples on the web focus on analytics.js. BTW, respect for your knowledge of this subject, srsly.

Comment: That would be really great.

Comment: I just realized that it is probably not possible to generate a client id that is compatible with both ga.js and the measurement protocol. You can use a class like https://code.google.com/p/serversidegoogleanalytics/ that emulate the old ga server calls, but frankly that's not something I will even try to explain. If you still want to know what the client id is for I'll be happy to post an answer, but I don't think I can help with the practical side of things.

Comment: @EikePierstorff Thanks for the information. My knowledge on the subject is inefficient anyway, so in the end I won't risk skewing my GA reports. I have solid registration info in the DB. I will stick to that. Regards.